# Different FQL results

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

If I run this query with the php sdk:

```
$fql ="http://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT+id,+text,time,+fromid+FROM+comment+WHERE+post_fbid+=+414571855318181+AND+is_private+=+0+AND+object_id+IN+%28SELECT+comments_fbid+FROM+link_stat+WHERE+url+=+%22http://griekenland.net/actie-pagina/%22%29"; 
$fql_query_result = file_get_contents($fql);
$fql_query_obj = json_decode($fql_query_result, true);
```

I get this response, which I think is wrong. Because it should filter on is_private and the comment hasn't been approved yet, so I don't see why it should return it.

```
Array
(
[data] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 394048867370480_2458709
                [text] => Kefalonia vind ik zo overweldigend mooi en afwisselend......speechless :O
                [time] => 1375532512
                [fromid] => removed
            )

    )
```

)

Now when I enter the same query directly in the browser http://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT+id,+text,time,+fromid+FROM+comment+WHERE+post_fbid+=+414571855318181+AND+is_private+=+0+AND+object_id+IN+%28SELECT+comments_fbid+FROM+link_stat+WHERE+url+=+%22http://griekenland.net/actie-pagina/%22%29 then it shows the expected response, which is nothing.

How can there be a difference like this? I mean it's either private or not? And I'm pretty sure the FQL call through php used to give the correct response until somewhere last week. If anyone knows what could possible cause this difference I would like to know :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using can_like instead? That should give you an idea of whether it's approved or not.

Comment: Just re-read your question - I think it might be due to the fact the comment wouldn't be private to your user if you're logged in as an admin - can you check that's not the case?